# comparing column to column in sql

Tags: php, sql

i have two tables,'student' and 'teacher'.'student' has 2 columns 'roll','class'.'teacher' has also 2 columns 'id','class'.i want to fetch some values of 'roll' column from 'student' table whose certain values of 'class' column will match with the values of 'class' column of 'teacher' table.can you please give me a solution to do that?

```
**student**              **teacher** 
roll     class           id       class

1         one            101       one
2         three          102       three
3         five           103       four
```

Comment: [**Understanding JOINs in MySQL and Other Relational Databases**](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    student.roll
FROM
    student
    INNER JOIN teacher ON student.class = teacher.class
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Roll FROM Student S
INNER JOIN Teacher T ON S.Class = T.Class